# chrome app w/node.js back end. App is issuing OPTIONS request in place of PUT

Tags: node.js, localhost, cors, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a chrome app and finally got to the point of issuing a PUT to the node.js server. My GET logic is working fine. My PUT however gets hijacked into a OPTIONS request. My requests are made to

```
http://localhost:4000/whatever
```

I read about the OPTIONS pass asking permission to do the PUT. I was under the impression that BROWSERS issue OPTIONS when CORS is requested, but didn't realize that a chrome app would also do this for me.

Is the app doing this because I didn't and I'm supposed to, or is this SOP that chrome will issue the OPTIONS request and I just issue my PUT that triggers it?

My PUT never makes it to the server. I've tried issuing my own OPTIONS just ahead of my PUT but so far nothing is working. The OPTIONS request makes it to the server (the default one or mine), but that's the end of the conversation.

At the server, all I'm doing to satisfy the OPTIONS request is as follows:

```
case 'OPTIONS':
   res.writeHead(200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT',
                       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"});
   break;
```

When I try issuing my own OPTIONS & PUT requests, I'm doing them with separate XMLHttpRequest objects. I don't see where the permission hand off from OPTIONS to PUT is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "preflighting", and browsers MUST preflight cross-origin requests if they fit specific criteria.  For example, if the request method is anything other than GET or POST, the browser must preflight the request.  You will need to handle these OPTIONS (preflight) requests properly in your server.

Presumably, your page is hosted on a port other than 4000, and the call to port 4000 is then considered cross-origin (in all browsers other than IE).  Don't issue the OPTIONS request yourself.  Chrome will then preflight your request.  Your server must respond appropriately.  The browser will handle the response to this OPTIONS request for you, and then send along the PUT as expected if the OPTIONS request was handled properly by your server.

There is [an excellent article on Mozilla Developer Network that covers all things CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).  If you plan on working in any cross-origin environment, you should read this article.  It will provide you with most of the knowledge necessary to understand the concepts required to properly deal with this type of an environment.

Comment: My "page" is a chrome app. Its hosted by installing it on my hard drive. It isn't hauled in via http in the traditional sense.   I've read the MozDev site as well as html5rocks and understand about preflight. What's not clear is how an "APP" differs from a traditional browser session. The only server I hit is my test server on port 4000 on my local box.

Comment: Here's the request header:   Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:PUT
Origin:chrome-extension://cenckmcibjncgjbokklgfkldnikknleb
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36      I get and try to respond to this request. What I can't get at are the response headers for the OPTIONS request as I never issued that request - the system issued it for me. All I have is what I tried to reply, which should be the same as the missing headers, but something tells me that's the issue.

Comment: I'm looking for all headers associated with the OPTIONS request (including the response).  It makes no difference who or what sends this request.  It should be available under the network tab of Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: What I've given is all I have according to the debugger. The OPTIONS request status is pending. That's what I don't understand. I replied with what I showed in my initial question. I know that section of code was executed because I wrapped it in console.log's. The res.writeHead(200, ...) should have been my reply but I don't know what happened to it. If I wait long enough, the OPTIONS request is automatically repeated, and I again reply but it goes nowhere.

Comment: I just figured out why my reply went nowhere. I forgot to do a res.end(); Now I get a failure of "Request header field contains/type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. I'll research that one. Thanks for your help.